# CountIF Function using Expression Builder

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, expressionbuilder

I want a simple text box that I'm programming in Access to read as follows,

```
CountIF(TableName)>FieldName1="Done" AND (TableName) FieldName2="Elective"
```

I started with this in the expression builder, but I'm getting lost in the syntax.

```
=Count([MyDatabase])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIF()` is an Excel spreadsheet function that is not supported in Access. I suspect that you want something like

```
=DCount("*", "TableName", "FieldName1=""Done"" AND FieldName2=""Elective""")
```

Comment: Gord you are the man!  Thank you!  My only suggestion to others is that I had to remove a "/" from one of my column title names.  Maybe it is just me.  If anyone has a really good syntax guide, it would be appreciated.